# Modifying Wordpress XML-RPC Built-Ins

Tags: plugins, xml-rpc, get-post

In short, I want to be able to modify the wp.getPost response to also return additional data, like the permalink. I thought it would be as easy as just calling the same function the xml-rpc code appears to call (`wp_getPost`):

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'nc_xmlrpc_methods' );

function nc_xmlrpc_methods( $methods ) {
    $methods['wp.getPost'] = 'my_getPost';
    return $methods;
}

function nc_getPost( $args ) {
    global $wp_xmlrpc_server;
    $post_obj = $wp_xmlrpc_server->wp_getPost( $args );
    $post = $post_obj->to_array();

    $post['permalink'] = get_permalink( $post_obj->ID );

    return $post;
}
```

Regarding the permalink, I know getPost returns a link already, but it's not helpful for drafts because I need to know the future link, not the current path.

I saw [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14759/extending-xml-rpc-best-practice) and it suggests extending `wp_xmlrpc_server`. I'm entirely new to PHP so I'm not entirely sure why that's necessary unless I'm really building out an extension to the API. Am I missing something basic with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
$post_obj['permalink'] = my_getDraftPermalink( $post_obj['post_id'] );
```

That's the correct syntax for getting the post_id. Then a custom function that gets the permalink the same way as the post dashboard UI is required. The dashboard uses `get_sample_permalink` and not `get_permalink`, which will return the draft path if the post isn't live.

```
function my_getDraftPermalink ( $post_id ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/post.php';

    list( $permalink, $postname ) = get_sample_permalink( $post_id );

    return str_replace( '%postname%', $postname, $permalink );
}
```